Reqwest crate fails with useless "builder error"
I'm trying to make a HTTP request to generate a key for meilisearch. It's not too complicated, but fails with a useless message. I've been debugging this for hours to no avail. Maybe you can spot a problem?
Here's the code
async fn generate_meili_api_key(state: &AppState, username: &str) -> Result<String, String> {
    println!("Preparing payload");

    let api_key_payload = json!({
        "name": format!("arcus-{}", username),
        "description": format!("Temporary key for user {}", username),
        "indexes": [format!("arcus-{}", username)],         // Modify this to limit to user-specific indices if required
        "actions": ["search", "documents.add", "tasks.get"],     // Limit to search actions
        "expiresAt": (Utc::now() + Duration::hours(12)).format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").to_string(), // Set an expiration date for the key
    });

    println!("Sending {api_key_payload} to {} with header {}",format!("{}/keys", state.meili_url), format!("Bearer {}", state.master_key));

    let response = state
        .client
        .post(format!("{}/keys", state.meili_url))
        .header("Authorization", format!("Bearer {}", state.master_key))
        .json(&api_key_payload)
        .send()
        .await
        .map_err(|e| format!("Failed to obtain key from meilisearch: {e}"))? // e -> "builder error"
        .json::<serde_json::Value>()
        .await.map_err(|_| "Failed to parse meilisearch response")?;

    println!("Response: {}", response);

    if let Some(key) = response["key"].as_str() {
        Ok(key.to_string())
    } else {
        Err("Meilisearch response did not contain an API key".to_owned())
    }
}

The error messages are returned to the client. The response I get is
❯ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/meilikeys --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "username": "user", "password": "password" }'
{"message":"Failed to generate API key: Failed to obtain key from meilisearch: builder error","api_key":null}⏎

and the logs of the service
Preparing payload
Sending {"actions":["search","documents.add","tasks.get"],"description":"Temporary key for user user","expiresAt":"2024-10-29T11:52:18Z","indexes":["arcus-user"],"name":"arcus-user"} to http://127.0.0.1:7700/keys with header Bearer <correct-token-here>

No request is sent to port 7700 (the meilisearch port reqwest should target). Any ideas?

The reason was a malformed bearer token.
This is because I read the token from a file, and it's surprisingly hard to not end up with a newline char there.
It gets worse, as it's even harder to test if that newline is there.
echo "newlinetest" > testnewline;

echo "/$(cat testnewline)/"
# -> /newlinetest/

The newline is there in the example above, but cat seems to omit it. Tokio, rightly so, does not.
Best way I found so far to not have it there is
echo -n "whatever you want" > "wherever_you_want"

or perhaps even better
printf '%s' "whatever you want" > "wherever you want"

as taken from here

which magically appends a newline to the end of the string in the file — it does no such thing, but many editors append a newline at the end of file if it's not there already. So the newline most certainly is in the file.

wow, you're right. It's surprisingly hard to not have that newline there. I thought vim wouldn't do crazy stuff like that. I'll update my answer

vim like many unix like programs interprets it as <eol> = end of line, a line terminator not separator. You should be able to :set noeol nofixnoeol
